# Force ArcMap to release unused Excel file

Tags: arcmap, excel

This is not a scripting issue or even a lock file issue.

I have an Excel file with one sheet.
I drag that one sheet into the ToC of ArcMap.
I look at the table.
I remove the sheet from the project.
Now the Excel sheet is locked for editing.
I return to ArcMap and close the project by starting a new one.
I disconnect the folder.
The Excel file is STILL locked.
I have to close ArcMap completely in order to edit the Excel file.
This results in having to go through the full 2 minute start up (yes, 2 minutes on a 2 month old machine).
Is there any other way of forcing ArcMap (10.8) to release its grip on a file it is no longer using?

Comment: Just tried Midavalo's linked solution in ArcMap 10.6.1. If you remove the table from the map and use refresh on the folder (using the ArcCatalog window), it releases the lock without having to close ArcMap.

Comment: I usually take the drive out physically and reseat it and find that 8 times out of 10 it releases the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a post by @KHibma on GeoNet that mentions how to release an Excel file lock from ArcCatalog

While this is about ArcCatalog, it might also work with ArcMap - maybe from the Catalog pane within the ArcMap application.

> 1. problem with ArcCatalog not releasing the file to use in Excel: If
>    you click the upper folder that the excel file lives in and refresh
>    (F5) - this should release the lock that ArcCatalog has on the file,
>    and Excel should be able to view it again. (no need to close
>    ArcCatalog)

GeoNet post: [ArcGIS Desktop v10 and Excel 2007 XLSX files lock and import problems](https://community.esri.com/thread/96291#comment-145149)

---

@danak has commented that this appears to work

> Just tried Midavalo's linked solution in ArcMap 10.6.1. If you remove
> the table from the map and use refresh on the folder (using the
> ArcCatalog window), it releases the lock without having to close
> ArcMap

Comment: Just like magic. I don't quite get why closing the project, disconnecting the folder etc. doesn't work but then there is much that I don't get when it comes to Arc.

Comment: Ah! Spoke too soon. Worked this morning but not anymore. Life with ArcMap is a true pleasure, much like sticking forks into your eyes is.